# worklight what is the event fired when the application exit

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Could you please help me to find the event or WL method fired when the worklight application exit ?
I have read the developer guide and may be i have miss it.
thanks.
regards,
jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you quit the app, the app quits. Nothing else happens.

Otherwise, you'll need to edit your question and be clearer.
Do you mean:

- when the app quits
- how to programmatically quit the app
- what happens when the app moves to the background
- something else...?

Availability:

- Android
- Windows Phone 7.5
- Windows Phone 8

---

Edit: based on the comment to this answer, you want to use [WL.App.overrideBackButton](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_app_overridebackbutton.html), so that once tapping on the physical Back button instead of quitting the app you could display a [WL.SimpleDialog](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_simpledialog.html) or alert or whatever else you want to do. An 'OK' button could then trigger [WL.App.close](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_closing_an_app.html) to quit the application (and a 'Cancel' button that will do nothing, to keep the user in the app).

Comment: sorry, yes when the application quit i want the user confirm yes/no he want to quit.

Comment: thanks it's exactly what i was looking for. bad news it doesn't work for blackberry.

Comment: Yes, WL.App.overrideBackButton is not available for BlackBerry. If your question is answered, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IBM Worklight ships with Apache Cordova, you can try to use [Cordova's Event API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events). Specifically the [pause event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause).

This is an event that fires when a Cordova application is put into the background.

```
//Add the event listener
function wlCommonInit() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

// Handle the pause event
function onPause() {
   //...
}
```